# Unable to import oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework in view ,after installing django-oauth-toolkit djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, oauth-2.0, django-authentication

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'App',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders', 
    'oauth2_provider',

]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    )
}
```

Please help to fix the issue ,as I unable to use **from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope** in my view